# ImportError: cannot import name Entity

Tags: python, django

I have two modules, like this:

**--models.py**

```
from myapp.filters import EntityFilter
class Entity(models.Model):
   //model definition

   def someMethod(self):
      entities = EntityFilter(...)
```

**--filters.py**

```
from myapp.models import Entity
class EntityFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:    
        model = Entity
        // ...
```

Obviously I got error *ImportError: cannot import name Entity*

How should I reorganize my code?

What do you think about this solution? Is it OK?

```
class Entity(models.Model):
   //model definition

   def someMethod(self):
      from myapp.filters import EntityFilter
      entities = EntityFilter(...)
```

It works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Has you try to do this?

```
from myapp.models import Entity
class EntityFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:    
        model = 'Entity'
        // ...
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. I got `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'`

Answer (score 0):

The method that you used to fix the problem is just fine and is quite common in python code that I've seen (at least when circular dependencies can't be avoided; it's also done to avoid over-polluting the global namespace when there aren't any circular dependencies to worry about).  For a good description of how import statements work in python, and why your work-around solved the issue, see this site, referenced in the answer to the "Circular dependency in Python" question noted in the comment by @mata above: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm.